# I am using define statement, but when I run the code, it says the variable is not declared

Tags: verilog

I have 16-bit instructions depending upon the 5-bit opcode field, 27-bit control signals are generated. I have defined these 27-bit values to its corresponding instruction word. The code is attached below. When I run this code it says `SW` is not declared.

```
`define NOP 27'b 000000000000000000000000000
`define SSS 27'b 000000000000000000010000000
`define SSN 27'b 000000000000000000100000000
`define SM 27'b 000000000000000001000000000
`define SW 27'b000000000000000010000000000
module top_module(
    input system_clk, 
    input [15:0] address,
    output [15:0] instruction,
    output [26:0] control_signal,
    output reg [7:0] LoadReg
    );
instruction_memory im(
.address(address),
.instruction(instruction)
);
instruction_decoder id(
.instr_in(instruction),
.cntrl_out(control_signal)
);

always@(posedge system_clk)
    begin
        case(control_signal)
        SW: LoadReg <= instruction[7:0]; 
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a `define` macro, you don't need to use the backtick, but when you use the macro you need to add the backtick.  Change:

```
    SW: LoadReg <= instruction[7:0];
```

to:

```
    `SW: LoadReg <= instruction[7:0];
```